# Unix command to rebuild device drivers

Tags: drivers, solaris

Would a Unix>“boot -r” command in Solaris rebuild the following device drivers?

I can’t access a tape library which I suspect is due to the error messages below.

Here are the Solaris error messages:

```
Feb  9 23:59:46 nodename scsi: [ID 583741 kern.warning] WARNING: /pci@306/pci@1/attach failed: soft state alloc failed
SUNW,qlc@0,1/fp@0,0 (fcp11): Request sense data length is too long (0xfffffff5).mp.outlc@0,1/fp@0,0 (fcp11): Request sense data len.

Feb 15 11:25:21 nodename fcip: [ID 950693 kern.warning] WARNING: fcip(20): port.
attach failed: soft state alloc failed741 kern.warning] WARNING: /pci@300/pci@2/
```

Comment: Which version of Solaris is this? And I guess the shell prompt you're seeing is "Unix>", but as drivers are very implementation-specific, the command you're looking for is not a UNIX command, but specifically a Solaris tool, but I'm really not versed in that world.

Comment: $uname -a:

The version of Solaris is 5.11 (11.4.41.107.2) sun4v sparc sun4v non-virtualized

Comment: These error messages are in /var/adm/ subdirectory.

Comment: The /var/adm/messages warnings persist.  They seem to apply to both tape libraries (pci@300 and  pci@306 are named in the messages about ‘sense data’:

Feb 16 10:46:22 node fcip: [ID 842839 kern.notice] NOTICE: fcip(10): port attach failed
Feb 16 10:46:22 node fctl: [ID 626979 kern.notice] NOTICE: fctl(10): attach failed for Fibre Channel IP ULP
Feb 16 10:46:32 node fcip: [ID 842839 kern.notice] NOTICE: fcip(0): port attach failed
Feb 16 10:46:32 node fctl: [ID 626979 kern.notice] NOTICE: fctl(0): attach failed for Fibre Channel IP ULP
Feb 16 10:46:42 node fcip: [ID 842839 kern.notice]

Comment: When was the last time you updated/patched your system?

Comment: A patch was needed.  Contacted Oracle to submit a trouble ticket.  The bug  is “SCSI Commands Sent To Fibre Channel Transport Fail Due To Auto Request Sense Data Length”.  A Solaris patch 11.4.42.113.1 was applied.  The SSCI errors were eliminated.